# jquery append in svg

Tags: jquery, svg

I have a generated svg which i am trying to target and style with a gradient according to https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_grad_linear.asp. Therefore I am trying to add the tags 'def', 'linearGradient' and 'stop' tags with attributes using .append . This is what i have currently

```
   this.body.append("svg:defs")
        .attr("cx","50%")
        .attr("cy","50%")
        .attr("fx","50%")
        .attr ("fy","50%")
        .attr ("id","MyGradient")
        .append("radialGradient")
        .append(":stop")
        .attr ("offset","0")
        .style("stop-color", "rgb(255,255,255)")
        .style("stop-opacity", "0")
        .append(":stop")
        .attr ("offset","100%")
        .style("stop-color", "rgb(0,0,255)")
        .style("stop-opacity", "1")
    ;
```

which outputs the following..

```
      <svg>
      <defs cx="50%" cy="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%" id="MyGradient">
      <radialGradient>
      <stop offset="0" style="stop-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); stop-opacity: 0;">
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: rgb(0, 0, 255); stop-opacity: 1;"/>
      </stop>
      </radialGradient>
      </defs>
      </svg>
```

which is close but the second 'stop' is a child of the first 'stop'. How could I adjust the code so that the 'stop's are siblings please?

Answer (score 0):

I think .append() might be chaining the previous append in a way that's creating it as a child of that element. Does it work if you change the second .append() to an .after()?

```
   this.body.append("svg:defs")
        .attr("cx","50%")
        .attr("cy","50%")
        .attr("fx","50%")
        .attr ("fy","50%")
        .attr ("id","MyGradient")
        .append("radialGradient")
        .append(":stop")
        .attr ("offset","0")
        .style("stop-color", "rgb(255,255,255)")
        .style("stop-opacity", "0")
        .after(":stop")
        .attr ("offset","100%")
        .style("stop-color", "rgb(0,0,255)")
        .style("stop-opacity", "1")
    ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No it errors with: TypeError: this.body.append(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).append(...).append(...).attr(...).style(...).style(...).after is not a function )

Comment: Might not be possible to chain them all at once then - maybe move the second stop to its own block and do something like `this.body.find('radialGradient').eq(0).append(":stop").attr ("offset","100%").style("stop-color", "rgb(0,0,255)").style("stop-opacity", "1")` ?